# How do I write and fix vector in c++

Tags: c++

I am making a question list that will store a list of questions. I am wondering if anyone could have me debug the problem.

QuestionList.h

```
#ifndef QUESTIONLIST_H
#define QUESTIONLIST_H
#include "Questions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class QuestionList {
private:
    vector<Questions*> _questionList;
public:
    QuestionList();
    QuestionList(const QuestionList& orig);
    virtual ~QuestionList();
    void AddQuestion(Questions *question);
    void RemoveQuestion(int i);


};
```

QuestionList.cpp

```
#include "QuestionList.h"

QuestionList::QuestionList() {
}

QuestionList::QuestionList(const QuestionList& orig) {
}

QuestionList::~QuestionList() {
}

QuestionList::QuestionList(){
    _questionList = vector<Questions*>;
}

QuestionList::AddQuestion(Questions *question){
    _questionList.push_back(*question);
}

QuestionList::RemoveQuestion(int i){
    _questionList.erase(_questionList.begin() + i);
}
```

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Don't do `_questionList = vector<Questions*>;` It is syntactically incorrect and unnecessary. By the time you enter the body of the constructor `_questionList` has already been default-constructed and is waiting for you to start adding items. Also no need to define the constructor twice. Compiler and linker don't like it when you do that. When it comes to definitions Highlander's law applies: [There can be only one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

Comment: It's a little hard for me to help you because you haven't said what problem you're having. I can see that you'll get some compile errors, but what are you actually encountering right now?

Comment: Don't do `_questionList.erase(_questionList.begin() + i);`. That will create a memory leak. Either make it a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), or `delete` it first.

Comment: Sidenote: `vector` is at its absolute best when it is allowed to directly contain objects. If you can, pass in an object and allow `vector` to make a copy. It will handle the rest, moving, copying, resizing, and destroying as needed.

Comment: Also, `_questionList.push_back(*question)` will cause some problems. You either need to not dereference the pointer (like this: `_questionList.push_back(question)`), or don;t store a vector of pointers at all.

Comment: @Chipster has a good point, but we can't be sure of a leak. Could be pointers to Automatic allocations (and Crom help the asker if their [lifetimes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) are governed by too narrow a [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Comment: Im still new to this so im not quite sure what the error. But I do believe the error is pointing to the vector

Comment: There are several errors. Suggestion: Back up your code and remove stuff until you have only one error. Then make a small program out of the remaining code required to produce that one error. If that doesn't make the error stand up and shout, "Over here! Fix me!" ask a question about that one error. Use [mcve] as inspiration.

Comment: General recommendation: Write small amounts of code at a time. If you write a few lines and then stop and test, there are usually few errors and they are easy to find because they're almost always in the few lines you just added. Once there are no more errors, you can write a few more lines. As you get better and better at programming you'll be able to write more code in each write-and-test cycle, but for now, the more you write at a time, the more you're going to have to throw out and rewrite because it's wrong.

Comment: Prefer to pass `std::vector` by *reference* or constant reference if the function doesn't modify the parameter.  A pointer can point to anywhere, valid objects or invalid memory areas.  By definition, the reference must exist.

Comment: So, what are the issues you are seeing?

Comment: Do yourself a favor:  design and code as if pointers are very evil.